# Inconsistent Extension Behavior on Google Chrome Installs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have observed inconsistent behavior using the Web Developer extension (Chris Pederick) in Google Chrome on these different machines:

- My PC running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- A VirturalBox Virtual Machine (VM) running Ubuntu 12 on my PC
- A VM running a updated, fresh install of Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit on my PC

I have the same version of Google Chrome and Web Developer installed on all these machines. However, for some reason, Web Developer does not work as expected on my PC. It works perfectly on the Ubuntu VM and the Windows VM.

On my PC, about 95% of the time the Custom Tools functions (Validate CSS, Validate HTML, etc.) in Web Developer do nothing when clicked (they should open new tabs to the W3C validators).

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Google Chrome on my PC several times. I have even manually gone through the file system and registry to completely remove all traces of Google Chrome before reinstalling. Nothing I've attempted so far has corrected this problem.

Of course, due to Google's 'field trials', all these machines have slightly different variations (as reported by chrome://version), but I would doubt that is the source of the problem.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Did you look at the correct place? I almost always browse in Incognito mode, and notice that clicking on "Validate HTML", etc. seems to do nothing. Later, I discover that the tab is opened in a different (non-incognito) window.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, I have never used Incognito, so for me, that is not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a possible clue...

It has baffled me why this problem NEVER occurs in my virtual machine (VM); only on the host. Same version of OS, Chrome, and Web Developer installed on both. May have discovered why.

My standard settings for VMs is to use only one CPU. As a test, I changed the VM to use two CPUs. BOOM! I can reproduce the problem on my VM. Change back to one CPU - can not reproduce the problem.

Does this suggest a problem with threading in Chrome?